# AngularJS .value(): not getting the Updated/Modified value in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have utilized the Value() Module in my AngularJS App.
I have declared and modified the Value, but I am not able to retrieve the modified or latest Value in a Controller.

- Flow is as follows:

  1. **STEP 1:** Initialize the Value with .value("key": "value")
  2. **STEP 2:** Modify the Value in RUN Block. If I do console.log() in this STEP, I am getting the desired output. That means the Value is getting updated.
  3. **STEP 3:** Access that modified or latest value in Controller for further process.

I have mentioned the STEPS in the Code below.

**app.module.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app", [
            "app.authentication"
        ])

        //STEP 1: Initialize the Value.
        .value("errorCollectionObject", {})

        .run(getErrorCollection)


    function getErrorCollection($rootScope, $location, $http, errorCollectionObject) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            $http.get("../app/core/error-collection.json")
                .then(function (response) {

                    //STEP 2: Modify/Update the Value.
                    errorCollectionObject = response.data; 

                });
        });
    }
})();
```

**login.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.authentication")
        .controller("LoginController", LoginController)

    LoginController.$inject = ["errorCollectionObject"];

    function LoginController(errorCollectionObject) {

        var vm = this;

        //STEP 3: Use the Modified or Latest Value
        //But instead of getting the Modified value, I am getting the null Object {} that I initialized in STEP 1.
        console.log(errorCollectionObject);
        //Output is: {}

    }

})();
```

Any idea what is going wrong? Or am I implementing the concept in a wrong way? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing the Value Module concept in the Wrong way. In my implementation method, the Value is not passed by Reference. And hence I am not getting the modified or updated Value.

In order to Pass the Value by Reference and to achieve the above-mentioned functionality, modify the Steps as below:

**STEP 1:**

```
var errObj = {errorCollection: null};
.value("errorCollectionObject", errObj)
```

**STEP 2:**

```
errorCollectionObject.errorCollection = response.data;
```

**STEP 3:**

```
console.log(errorCollectionObject.errorCollection);
```

You will get the Modified or Updated Value in Step 3.
Hope it helps somebody. :)